# How to create a thread without ThreadGroup?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadgroup

This question was asked in an interview for the Senior Developer Role.
As I don't have any exposure to Java multi-threading and concurrency. So, I could not answer this.

> Every thread we create is part of a ThreadGroup. Then how do we create
> a thread without ThreadGroup?

Comment: It is off-topic to ask about external resources, so I edited out that part of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to create a thread without ThreadGroup.

For more details look here: [https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~mead/Java-tutorial/essential/threads/group.html](https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/%7Emead/Java-tutorial/essential/threads/group.html)

> "If you create a new Thread without specifying its group in the
> constructor, the runtime system automatically places the new thread in
> the same group as the thread that created it (known as the current
> thread group and the current thread, respectively). So, if you leave
> the thread group unspecified when you create your thread, what group
> contains your thread?
>
> When a Java application first starts up, the Java runtime system
> creates a ThreadGroup named main. Unless specified otherwise, all new
> threads that you create become members of the main thread group."

And here: http://www.java2s.com/example/java-book/thread-group.html

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually answers question.

Comment: @talex It is not possible to create a thread without ThreadGroup.

Comment: Please state that explicitly in your answer.